# Query NOT IN assistance

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull out the names where either number 1 or 8 is loaded in isolation,  but query not doing that.

So want to see where name only has 8 or only has 1 but not both

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`name` varchar(7), `number` int);

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`name`, `number`)
VALUES
    ('renee', 1),
    ('renee', 8),
    ('eugene', 1),
    ('jacques', 1),
    ('jacques', 8),
    ('avril', 8);

SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE Number IN ('1')
AND Number NOT IN ('8')
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to approach this might be to aggregate by name, restricting to 1 or 8 number values, then retaining only names having one distinct number.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table1
WHERE Number IN (1, 8)
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Number) = 1
```

Comment: Hmmm... Why `COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) = 1`? This query will show all rows.

Comment: Really ugly typo...sorry

Comment: Now is ok. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Following query does exactly what was asked, it may not work for example if records (Name,Number) are not unique `=1` may be changed to `>=1`.

```
SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE Number in (1,8)
group by name
having count(case when number=1 then 1 end)=1
and count(case when number=8 then 1 end)=0
 or count(case when number=1 then 1 end)=0
and count(case when number=8 then 1 end)=1
```